# Basic bootstrap typeahead with example

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

For some reason basic typeahead example doesn't work on any of my web servers, but I'm able to get it working here - http://jsfiddle.net/H4Qmh/12/

Any differences or issue in the code below comparing with code posted on jsfiddle? Can you confirm that code below works for you? (You should be able to see results just by typing h, i or s)

```
<html>
<head>
<link href="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="well">
<input autocomplete="off" type="text" class="span3" data-provide="typeahead" data-items="4" placeholder="Type in letter h, i or s" data-source='["iPhone", "HTC", "Samsung"]' >
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you must provide the code used in your server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have just replaced your bootstrap with the bootstrap typeahead js file. and it starts running.

> https://github.com/biggora/bootstrap-ajax-typeahead/tree/master/src

Comment: What a nice help! I just downloaded `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/biggora/bootstrap-ajax-typeahead/master/src/bootstrap-typeahead.js` and replaced bootstrap script line with `<script src="bootstrap-typeahead.js"></script>`. It worked.

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
<head>

    <!--    jquery-->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="well">
        <input autocomplete="off" type="text" class="span3" data-provide="typeahead" data-items="4" placeholder="type in letter h, i or s" data-source='["iPhone", "HTC", "Samsung"]'>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Your `bootstrap cdn` link was returning you an `HTML` file and not a `CSS` file.